# Sql query from excel vba to access to retrun data that match Array

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I would like to know if there is a way without using loop to get multiply results from database using array?

Lets assume that we got this array:

```
Dim A As Variant
myUserName  = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
```

I want to know if there is a way to pass the array like that:

```
mySQLst = "SELECT * FROM UserTb WHERE (((UserTb.Nickname)='" & myUserName & "'));"
```

and get back all users who in the database answer the strings in ther array.
I use Access database and Excel vba for this.

thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Join*:

```vb
myUserName  = Array("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
mySQLst = "SELECT * FROM UserTb WHERE UserTb.Nickname IN ('" & Join(myUserName, "','") & "');"
```